# An error while trying to generate a summary table using qwraps2

Tags: r, qwraps2

I am working in R markdown and using qwraps2 to generate a summary table.
I get an error message but I can not spot where is the errors in my code. Any one can help, please

```
Library (tidyverse)
Library (readxl)
Library (qwraps2)

options(qwraps2_markup = "markdown")

ATT <- read_excel('E:/MY PROJECTS/OSTEOTOMY ACL/ATT.xlsx')
```

Flexion_Degrees Load_Direction  Load_N  Osteotomy_Type  PTS_Degrees
30  Anterior    134 Native  0
90  Anterior    134 Native  0
30  Anterior    134 AOWO    5
90  Anterior    134 AOWO    5

```
{r, results='asis'}
ATT_summary <-
  list( "Posterior Tibial Slope (degrees)" =
       list("min"       = ~ min(PTS_Degrees, na_rm = TRUE),
            "max"       = ~ max(PTS_Degrees, na_rm = TRUE),
            "mean (sd)" = ~ qwraps2::mean_sd(PTS_Degrees, na_rm = TRUE, denote_sd = "paren")),
    "Flexion Angle" =
       list("min"       = ~ min(Flexion_Degrees, na_rm = TRUE),
            "max"       = ~ max(Flexion_Degrees, na_rm = TRUE),
            "mean (sd)" = ~ qwraps2::mean_sd(Flexion_Degrees, na_rm = TRUE, denote_sd = "paren")),
       "Anterior Tibial Translation (mm)" =
       list("min"       = ~ min(ATT_ACL, na_rm = TRUE),
            "max"       = ~ max(ATT_ACL, na_rm = TRUE),
            "mean (sd)" = ~ qwraps2::mean_sd(ATT_ACL, na_rm = TRUE, denote_sd = "paren")),
       "Applied Load in Newtons" =
       list("min"       = ~ min(Load_N, na_rm = TRUE),
            "max"       = ~ max(Load_N, na_rm = TRUE),
            "mean (sd)" = ~ qwraps2::mean_sd(Load_N, na_rm = TRUE, denote_sd = "paren")),
       "Load Direction" =
       list("Unloaded" = ~ qwraps2::n_perc0(Load_Direction == UNLOADED),
         "Anterior" = ~ qwraps2::n_perc0(Load_Direction == Anterior),
            "Axial Compression" = ~ qwraps2::n_perc0(Load_Direction == Axial_Compression),
         "Anterior and Axial Compression" = ~ qwraps2::n_perc0(Load_Direction == Anterior_Axial compression)),
    "Osteotomy Type" =
       list("Native" = ~ qwraps2::n_perc0(Osteotomy_Type == Native),
            "AOWO"  = ~ qwraps2::n_perc0(Osteotomy_Type == AOWO),
            "ACWO"  = ~ qwraps2::n_perc0(Osteotomy_Type == ACWO),
            "MOWO"  = ~ qwraps2::n_perc0(Osteotomy_Type == MOWO),
            "LCWO"  = ~ qwraps2::n_perc0(Osteotomy_Type == LCWO))
       )
Summary_ATT_STATS <- summary_table(ATT, ATT_summary)
Summary_ATT_STATS
```

I get the following error message:

Error: unexpected symbol in:
"            "Axial Compression" = ~ qwraps2::n_perc0(Load_Direction == Axial_Compression),
"Anterior and Axial Compression" = ~ qwraps2::n_perc0(Load_Direction == Anterior_Axial compression"

When I removed the last 2 variables and used the following code,  I got the following error

```
> `{r, results='asis'} ATT_summary <-   list( "Posterior Tibial Slope
> (degrees)" =
>        list("min"       = ~ min(PTS_Degrees, na_rm = TRUE),
>             "max"       = ~ max(PTS_Degrees, na_rm = TRUE),
>             "mean (sd)" = ~ qwraps2::mean_sd(PTS_Degrees, na_rm = TRUE, denote_sd = "paren")),
>     "Flexion Angle" =
>        list("min"       = ~ min(Flexion_Degrees, na_rm = TRUE),
>             "max"       = ~ max(Flexion_Degrees, na_rm = TRUE),
>             "mean (sd)" = ~ qwraps2::mean_sd(Flexion_Degrees, na_rm = TRUE, denote_sd = "paren")),
>        "Anterior Tibial Translation (mm)" =
>        list("min"       = ~ min(ATT_ACL, na_rm = TRUE),
>             "max"       = ~ max(ATT_ACL, na_rm = TRUE),
>             "mean (sd)" = ~ qwraps2::mean_sd(ATT_ACL, na_rm = TRUE, denote_sd = "paren")),
>        "Applied Load in Newtons" =
>        list("min"       = ~ min(Load_N, na_rm = TRUE),
>             "max"       = ~ max(Load_N, na_rm = TRUE),
>             "mean (sd)" = ~ qwraps2::mean_sd(Load_N, na_rm = TRUE, denote_sd = "paren")),
>        ) Summary_ATT_STATS <- summary_table(ATT, ATT_summary) Summary_ATT_STATS
```

Error in list(`Posterior Tibial Slope (degrees)` = list(min = ~min(PTS_Degrees,  :
argument 5 is empty

Answer (score 0):

The problem is likely in the construction of the "Load Direction" row group.  The string values that `Load_Direction` are compared against need to be in quotes.  See below.

```r
   "Load Direction" =
     list("Unloaded" = ~ qwraps2::n_perc0(Load_Direction == "UNLOADED"),
          "Anterior" = ~ qwraps2::n_perc0(Load_Direction == "Anterior"),
          "Axial Compression" = ~ qwraps2::n_perc0(Load_Direction == "Axial_Compression"),
          "Anterior and Axial Compression" = ~ qwraps2::n_perc0(Load_Direction == "Anterior_Axial compression")),
```